# Find the Laplace transform of this function $f(t)=\int _0^t(t-\tau)\cos(2\tau)d\tau$

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform

Find the Laplace transform of this function $f(t)=\int _0^t(t-\tau)\cos(2\tau)d\tau$

**My work:**

$\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}=\mathcal{L}\{\int_0^t(t-\tau)\cos(2\tau
)d\tau\}$

Here I'm a little stuck, I think I need use

$\mathcal{L}\{\int_0 ^tf(t)dt\}=\dfrac{F(s)}{s}$

but I'm a little confused with that. Can someone help me?

Comment: This is a convolution. There is a standard formula for the transform of a convolution.

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply the convolution theorem. With the assumptions of the convolution theorem satisfied, if:
$$f(t)=g(t){\ast}h(t)=\int_0^t{g(\tau)h(t-\tau)d\tau}=\int_0^t{g(t-\tau)h(\tau)d\tau}$$ 
where '$\ast$' implies convolution, then:
$$F(s)=G(s)H(s)$$
**In order to apply this theorem to your problem**:
Let $$f(t)=g(t){\ast}h(t)=\int_0^t{g(t-\tau)h(\tau)d\tau}$$ 
Conveniently choosing $g(t)=t$ and $h(t)=cos(2t)$ then
$$g(t-\tau)=t-\tau$$ and
$$h(\tau)=cos(2\tau)$$
Gives $$f(t)=g(t){\ast}h(t)=\int_0^t{(t-\tau)cos(2\tau)d\tau}$$ which is in the form of the problem to be solved.

Now,
$$G(s)=\frac{1}{s^2}$$
and $$H(s)=\frac{s}{s^2+4}$$

Theferfore
$$F(s)=G(s)H(s)=\frac{1}{s^2}\frac{s}{s^2+4}=\frac{1}{s(s^2+4)}$$